# How to align uncertainty with siunitx in table

Tags: tables, formatting, siunitx, alignment

I have a table that contains SI units using the `siunitx` package which have different digits of uncertainties. How can I easily go about aligning them to the `\pm`?

I've tried playing around with the `siunitx`'s provided `S` column and different formatting options but couldn't get it to work properly. Any suggestions?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single,table-align-uncertainty=true}
\title{alignment-mwe}
\author{robin_schmidt}
\date{April 2022}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cr}
    A     &  \SI{1272.4 \pm 38.5}{\ms}\\
    B     & \SI{1272.4 \pm 8.5}{\ms} \\ 
    C     & \SI{1272.4 \pm 18.5}{\ms}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got around it by using the workaround described [here](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/370). This is provided in [`siunitx`](//ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) by the switch `table-align-uncertainty` when using an `S`-column.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true,multi-part-units=single,table-align-uncertainty=true}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c S }
  A & 1.4(5)       ~ ms \\
  B & 12.4(50.5)   ~ ms \\ 
  C & 1272.4(18.5) ~ ms
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```